# Resizing toolbar in autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am using Autodesk forge version v7.*
I want to resize my toolbar once a resize event is triggered. I used the 'viewer.resize' code as below:

this.forge2DView = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('drawingCanvas'), { extensions: ['Autodesk.DocumentBrowser'] });

// loaded the file

this.forge2DView.addEventListener("resize", function (event) {
this.forge2DView.resize();

But it is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Only events under `Autodesk.Viewing` are supported by `addEventListener`, e.g. `Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/events/

You can listen to the `resize` event like this:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT, function (event) {
    // calling here `viewer.resize();` would create an infinite loop
    console.log("resize");
});
```